# por que no me da el número de apariciones de un dato en una matriz

Tags: java

estoy tratando de hacer un metodo que dada una matriz de enteros me de el numero de veces que aparece un numero.

```
public class Matriz {
    //Indicar el número de apariciones de un dato en una matriz de enteros.
    public static int numdeapariciones(int[][] m) {
        int apariciones = m [0][0];
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) { 
            for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
                if (m [i][j]== apariciones);
                apariciones = m[i][j] ;
                }

        }
        return apariciones ;
    }
}
```

Comment: apariciones++;  ........

Comment: ¿Solo necesitas que te retorne el número de apariciones del primer elemento de la matriz?

Comment: yo necesito que me retorne los numeros que se repitan en filas y columnas de la matriz

Comment: Entonces de que dato hay que contar las apariciones de uno específico o de cada uno de los datos de la matriz. La matriz está ordenada o no?

Comment: hay que coseguirlos de cada uno de los datos de la matriz y la matriz no esta ordenada

Answer (score -1):

No veo en que parte del código sumas las apariciones solo  tienes que ir sumandolas algo como apariciones++ o apariciones +=1